# mail function not working properly

Tags: php, email

Can someone please help me with my mail function issue.

I want to receive text values in table and an attachment. Right now I am receiving the table code instead of the code output and the attachment.

And If I delete the modification I made for the attachment then I get the right output but only text.

```
            <?php
            include("config.php");

                 $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
                 $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
                 $email = $_POST['email'];
                 $fn1 = $_POST['fn1'];
                 $fn2 = $_POST['fn2'];
                 $fn3 = $_POST['fn3'];
                 $fn4 = $_POST['fn4'];
                 $fn28= $_POST['fn28'];


                $subject = 'test';


                //get file details we need
                $file_tmp_name    = $_FILES['fn28']['tmp_name'];
                $file_name        = $_FILES['fn28']['name'];
                $file_size        = $_FILES['fn28']['size'];
                $file_type        = $_FILES['fn28']['type'];
                $file_error       = $_FILES['fn28']['error'];

                $handle = fopen($file_tmp_name, "r");
                $content = fread($handle, $file_size);
                fclose($handle);
                $encoded_content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));


                    $boundary = md5("vikas"); 
                    //header
                    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"; 
                    $headers .= "From:".$email."\r\n"; 
                    $headers .= "Reply-To: ".$email."" . "\r\n";
                    $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary = $boundary\r\n\r\n"; 

                    $msg = "
                        <table border='1'>
                        <tbody>
                            <th>
                                <td><h3>Contact Information</h3></td>
                            </th>
                            <tr>
                                <td><b>Borrower's Full Name</b></td>
                                <td><span style='color:#F34536;'> $firstname $lastname </span></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><b>Email</b></td>
                                <td><span style='color:#F34536;'> $email</span></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><b>Attach Key Documents (optional)</b></td>
                                <td><span style='color:#F34536;'> $fn28</span></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                        </table>
                    ";

                    $msg1 = chunk_split(base64_encode($msg));

                    //plain text 
                    $body = "--$boundary\r\n";
                    $body .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
                    $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n\r\n"; 
                    $body .= $msg1; 

                    //attachment
                    $body .= "--$boundary\r\n";
                    $body .="Content-Type: $file_type; name=\"$file_name\"\r\n";
                    $body .="Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$file_name\"\r\n";
                    $body .="Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
                    $body .="X-Attachment-Id: ".rand(1000,99999)."\r\n\r\n"; 
                    $body .= $encoded_content; 

                    mail($toemail, $subject, $body, $headers)

            ?>
```

Comment: can some one help me with a mail function. I want to show text field in a table  and an attachment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is because you have this line:

```
$body .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
```

All code is sent in `text-plain`, delete it and change it as `text/html` in `$header`:

```
$header .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n';
$header .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n';
```

Comment: I did vote. https://www.dropbox.com/s/dlfc11dgq9td9oz/Screenshot%202015-10-16%2008.04.34.png?dl=0